# Program does not loop

Tags: python, loops

I'm curious as to why this program is not looping. The program will run once but when another game is played it doesn't record the winner and quits.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated!

Here is the Python program:

```
import random
random.seed()

print ("For each round please select from the following warriors: ")
print ("'C' or 'c' for Cowboy")
print ("'N' or 'n' for Ninja")
print ("'B' or 'b' for Bear")
print ("'Q' or 'q' for quit")
print()

gamesPlayed = 0

print ("Round", gamesPlayed +1, ":")
warriorStr = input("Please choose a warrior: ")
warriorStr = warriorStr.lower()

while not warriorStr.isalpha():
    print()
    print ("That's not a valid choice!")
    warriorStr = input("Please enter a weapon: ")

computer = random.choice("cnb")

count = 0
winCount = 0
lossCount = 0
tieCount = 0

if warriorStr == "n" or "N" and computer == "c" or "C":
    winCount = winCount + 1
    print ("You win")
elif warriorStr == "c" or "C" and computer == "b" or "B":
    winCount = winCount + 1
    print ("You win")
elif warriorStr == "b" or "B" and computer == "n" or "N":
    winCount = winCount + 1
    print ("You win")
elif warriorStr == "c" and computer == "n":
    lossCount = lossCount + 1
    print ("Computer wins")
elif warriorStr == "b" and computer == "c":
    lossCount = lossCount + 1
    print ("Computer wins")
elif warriorStr == "n" and computer == "b":
    lossCount = lossCount + 1
    print ("Computer wins")
elif warriorStr == "c" and computer == "c":
    tieCount = tieCount + 1
    print ("You tied")
elif  warriorStr == "n" and computer == "n":
    tieCount = tieCount + 1
    print ("You tied")
elif warriorStr == "b" and computer == "b":
    tieCount = tieCount + 1
    print ("You tied")

gamesPlayed = gamesPlayed + 1
print()
print ("Round", gamesPlayed +1, ":")
warriorStr = input("Choose a warrior: ")

if warriorStr == "q" and "Q":
    print("Game Over!")
    print ("You have played a total of", gamesPlayed, "games.")
    print ("You won", winCount, "times")
    print ("The computer won", lossCount, "times")
    print ("You tied", tieCount, "times")
```

Comment: Your program contains one loop (`while not warriorStr.isalpha()`). Why would the rest of it loop?

Comment: I want to keep playing until user enters "q" to quit

Comment: You need to wrap a large portion of this code in a while loop. Pretty much all of it.

Comment: because python cannot read your mind ;) it will only loop when you tell it to loop. Besides, please encapsulate more, use more functions, it will make your code more readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the whole thing in a while loop.
Try something *like* this:

```
warriorStr = input("Please choose a warrior: ")
warriorStr = warriorStr.lower()

acceptables = ['a','c','n','q']   

while warriorStr not 'q' and warriorStr in acceptables:

    warriorStr = input("Please enter a weapon: ")

    computer = random.choice("cnb")

    count = 0
    winCount = 0
    lossCount = 0
    tieCount = 0

    if warriorStr == "n" or "N" and computer == "c" or "C":
        winCount = winCount + 1
        print ("You win")
    elif warriorStr == "c" or "C" and computer == "b" or "B":
        winCount = winCount + 1
        print ("You win")
    elif warriorStr == "b" or "B" and computer == "n" or "N":
        winCount = winCount + 1
        print ("You win")
    elif warriorStr == "c" and computer == "n":
        lossCount = lossCount + 1
        print ("Computer wins")
    elif warriorStr == "b" and computer == "c":
        lossCount = lossCount + 1
        print ("Computer wins")
    elif warriorStr == "n" and computer == "b":
        lossCount = lossCount + 1
        print ("Computer wins")
    elif warriorStr == "c" and computer == "c":
        tieCount = tieCount + 1
        print ("You tied")
    elif  warriorStr == "n" and computer == "n":
        tieCount = tieCount + 1
        print ("You tied")
    elif warriorStr == "b" and computer == "b":
        tieCount = tieCount + 1
        print ("You tied")

    gamesPlayed = gamesPlayed + 1
    print()
    print ("Round", gamesPlayed +1, ":")
    warriorStr = input("Choose a warrior: ")

print("Game Over!")
print ("You have played a total of", gamesPlayed, "games.")
print ("You won", winCount, "times")
print ("The computer won", lossCount, "times")
print ("You tied", tieCount, "times")
```

Comment: ...Thanks! That helps!!

Comment: One last thing...
I only want users to input characters "a", "c", "n", and "q".
Is there a simple way of doing so??

Comment: There are several ways of doing that... One quick and dirty way would be to add the condition to your while statement. I've edited my original answer.

Comment: ...I also got it to work by adding an Else statement at the end...
Thanks for all your input!!

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to upvote my answer please!